# Request to server when app in background

Tags: iphone, background-process

I need that my app will send some data to server every six hours for example. Purpose is that it will send request to server even when app in background. As I know only thinks GPS, Music, Push Notifications work on background. Also, as I know `UIApplication` method `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` works not for a long time after app goes on background. Guys, anybody have idea how to implement this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply not possible within the limits of the current iOS SDK. The only kind of apps that can update their content regularly from the background are Newsstand apps and for them, the interval is 24 hours AFAIK and the entire updating process is largely triggered by Apple.

Comment: :(( Ok. What you mean it's not possible with current IOS SDK? Is it mean that app not will pass check for App Store? 'Cause I workin' on enterprise version. Not for App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app falls into one of the categories you mention, the short answer is you can't. The only exception is for Newsstand apps.

But: what data would you be sending to the server if your app isn't running? If you send data to the server when something happens then the server will always be up-to-date. If the user isn't running the app then, by definition, nothing has happened and the server is still "in sync" with the client. (Yes, this potentially makes the server harder to code.)

Comment: Nope. It's simply POST method with some string data. Nothing happens. I need to send this data every 6 hours.

Comment: Without knowing more about your usecase it's impossible to say much more than "it's not possible." I tried...